# Android Multipart POST - Class Not Found Exception for org.apache.comons.io.IOUtils

Tags: android, multipart

I have the following jar files in my project's lib directory.

apache-mime4j-core-0.72.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
httpclient-4.2.jar
httpcore-4.2.jar
httpmime-4.2.jar

I also right click on the project name and BUILD PATH to include these jar files.
But when I ran my application in the emulator, I got a Class Not Found Exception for org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils and several other classes that are in the above mentioned jar files.

I will appreciate anyone who knows how to fix the problem. 
Thanks, android learner

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed the jar file inside the /libs folder of your project? ADT plugin will pick those jars and bundle them with APK.

Comment: This is most likely the issue.  Remove any other ways that you might have tried to reference the library in your Eclipse project, then pop it in the libs folder like Anirudh said.

Comment: Yes. I do have these jar files in the /libs folder.

Comment: make sure you have the latest ADT plugin and SDK tools.